# Finding a row in 2d Numpy array with values x,y,z in

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search, indexing

I have

```
import numpy as np
np_array = np.array([[0,4],[0,5],[3,5],[6,8],[9,1],[6,1]])
rows=np.where(np_array[:,0]==6)and np.where(np_array[:,1]==1)
print(np_array[rows])
```

Expected answer

```
[6,1]
```

Answer from code

```
[[9 1]
 [6 1]]
```

What I would like is the index of where `[6,1]` is.

I must be missing something.

Comment: Your question is confusing. First you say the expected output is `[6, 1]`, then you say the expected output is the index of the row `[6, 1]`. What is it? And what if `[6, 1]` appears more than once in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `where`, just using indexing.

```py
import numpy as np

np_array = np.array([[0, 4], [0, 5], [3, 5], [6, 8], [9, 1], [6, 1]])

rows = (np_array[:, 0] == 6) & (np_array[:, 1] == 1)

print(np_array[rows][0])
```

You can get the indices with `np.where(rows)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect. What is 'Where' for then? do you know of a good place to study Numpy?

Comment: `where` can be useful to compare two arrays. However, I am simply just more familiar with this indexing style.

Usually, the documentation explains things very well (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). For specific answers I found StackOverflow the best. For general overview and practice, I found this resource (and its references) to be really good: https://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/from-python-to-numpy/.